# How to get the value returned from a promise and use it in other file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, promise, ioc-container

I have created a small project to show the issue.

There 5 files in this project. 
A container file which contain all the dependencies injection; A service file which contain the function I need to run; A controller file which calls the function in service file; An app file which is the highest level application which will call all the controller files, in this example there is only 1; An index.js file which is the start point of the application.

container.js:

```
const {
    createContainer,
    asValue,
    asFunction,
    asClass,
} = require('awilix');

const container = createContainer();

const Controller = require('./controller');
const Service = require('./service');

container.register({
    controller: asClass(Controller).singleton(),
    service: asClass(Service).singleton(),
})

const App = require('./app');

container.register({
    app: asClass(App).singleton(),
})

module.exports = container;
```

service.js:

```
module.exports = class Service {

    doService() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve("Hello from service!"), 2000);
        });
    }

}
```

controller.js:

```
module.exports = class Controller {
    constructor({ service }) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    doWork() {
        this.service.doService().then(response => {
            this.message = response;
            return this.message;
        })
    }
}
```

app.js:

```
module.exports = class App {
    constructor({ controller }) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    async start() {
        try {
            this.doc = await this.controller.doWork();
        } catch (err) {

        }
        console.log(this.doc);
    }
}
```

index.js:

```
const container = require('./container');

const app = container.resolve('app');

app.start();
```

My goal is that I can see the doc attribute in app.js becomes 'Hello from service!' and be able to console.log it out. The call sequence should be:

index.js --> app.js --> controller.js --> service.js --> controller.js --> app.js

All the dependencies are injected in the container.js using awilix js.

I am very sure is something that I messed up with return it from  promise in controller.js, because if I use other sync function it worked.

Please let me know why I am wrong, how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return the promise that you create in controller.doWork(). In your "start" function when you await the result of controller.doWork(), there is no value. The function does not return a promise, or anything for that matter, to "await."

```
module.exports = class Controller {
constructor({ service }) {
    this.service = service;
}

//Needs to return a value.
doWork() {
    // This is a promise, you need to return it.
    //this.service.doService().then(response => {
    //    this.message = response;
    //    return this.message;
    //})

    return this.service.doService().then(response => {
        this.message = response;
        return this.message;
    })
}
```

The await statement in app.js is syntax sugar for something like the following:

```
 this.controller.doWork().then(response => {
      this.doc = response;
 });
```

Instead of writing that, we can use await to "automatically" unwrap the value returned by the promise, and assign it to a variable.

It also pauses the function "start", which allows us to avoid having to write the remainder of the function within the "then" statement:

```
this.doc = await this.controller.doWork();
if (this.doc.type === "error") { 
    throw new Error(this.doc) 
}
```

Is much cleaner than:

```
this.controller.doWork().then(response => {
    this.doc = response;
    if (this.doc.type === "error") { 
        throw new Error(this.doc) 
    }
});
```

Especially as the code that is dependent upon the value of doWork() gets longer and/or more complicated.

Comment: it worked, Thx buddy. I need to understrand more about promise. So to make it work, we basicly need to return a promise which will return a message variable?

Comment: Yes, your function needs to return a promise. In your case, if you didn't want to store the response in this.message, you could simply write "return this.service.doService();"
doService is a promise, so you've satisfied that requirement. I'll add something to the post to clarify the await statement a bit.

Comment: Thx, you are the best.! :)